# Drag and drop a GML file with Openlayers 6.12 with several indeterminate projections (EPSG:2154,EPSG:4326,EPSG:32620,etc)

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to view a gml file on drag and drop.
I add GML formats to the DragAndDrop interaction.
But the dragAndDropInteraction is not activated when I drag and drop such a file.
On the other hand I wonder how to handle indeterminate projections in this process
An example of GML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ogr:FeatureCollection
     gml:id="aFeatureCollection"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://ogr.maptools.org/ chlorMart.xsd"
     xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
     xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
  <gml:boundedBy><gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32620"><gml:lowerCorner>717790.1621 1616707.973312</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>718366.00456 1617330.214752</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></gml:boundedBy>
                                                                                                                             
  <ogr:featureMember>
    <ogr:chlorMart gml:id="chlorMart.0">
      <gml:boundedBy><gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32620"><gml:lowerCorner>717790.1621 1616707.973312</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>718366.00456 1617330.214752</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></gml:boundedBy>
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32620" gml:id="chlorMart.geom.0"><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>718210.439867 1616986.346574 718097.188448 1616860.798451 718069.891474 1616811.676541 718034.413648 1616747.547099 718023.502556 1616707.973312 717997.576705 1616739.359337 717980.589711 1616761.586485 717873.37374 1616901.828488 717803.314641 1616989.227362 717790.1621 1617006.815097 717814.720588 1617031.380751 717865.214452 1617070.943449 717907.511233 1617105.057187 717923.880847 1617122.794086 717959.365868 1617148.719236 717992.113005 1617171.924866 718028.958607 1617195.120386 718083.534332 1617230.593583 718119.01939 1617257.888527 718147.676307 1617281.084272 718184.513475 1617297.460811 718204.981481 1617312.478004 718226.818465 1617330.214752 718270.333143 1617270.962405 718366.00456 1617145.988439 718331.888482 1617121.433047 718210.439867 1616986.346574</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></ogr:geometryProperty>
      <ogr:gid>13734</ogr:gid>
      <ogr:id>1</ogr:id>
      <ogr:taux_chlor>2.127</ogr:taux_chlor>
      <ogr:prec_lab>Contour géographique précis</ogr:prec_lab>
      <ogr:legende>Fortement contaminé</ogr:legende>
    </ogr:chlorMart>
  </ogr:featureMember>
</ogr:FeatureCollection>
```

The code :

```
var dragAndDropInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragAndDrop({
                        formatConstructors: [
                        ol.format.GPX,
                        ol.format.GeoJSON,
                        ol.format.IGC,
                        ol.format.KML,
                        ol.format.TopoJSON,
                        ol.format.GML32,
                        ol.format.GML3,
                        ol.format.GML
                        ]
                    });
   var map = new ol.Map({
                        target: 'map',
                        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([dragAndDropInteraction]), //on rajoute le dragAndDropInteraction
                        layers: [],
                        view: new ol.View({
                            //projection: "EPSG:3857",
                            center: center,
                            zoom: zoom
                        })
                    });
dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function(e) { 
                            const files = e
                            console.log('e',e)
                            console.log('files2',files)
                            //gml etc
                            proj4.defs('EPSG:32620','+proj=utm +zone=20 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs');
                                ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
                            console.log('files.features',files.features)
    var AnnotImportStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: [255, 255, 255, 0.4],
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#ff0000',
                                width: 4
                            })
                        });
                        const featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: 'red',
                                width: 1
                            })
                        });
                        const vectorSource2 = new ol.source.Vector({
                            features: files.features,
                        });
                        const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                            source: vectorSource2,
                            style: AnnotImportStyle,
                                visible: true,
                                boutonExtent: true,
                                boutonFeatureInfo: true,
                                dragAndDrop: true
                        })
                        map.addLayer(
                        vectorLayer
                        );
                        var name = file_name.substr(0,   file_name.lastIndexOf('.'));
                        vectorLayer.set('name', name);
                        map.getView().fit(vectorSource2.getExtent());
                });
```

Comment: It's not question of drag and drop, first you should try to display this GML in OL. No matter what I tried (GML format, WFS format), I could not display it, always got 0 features.

Comment: OK. does this mean that the openlayers 6.12 parser can't read it?
this gml is from qgis.
In this case I will design my own xml parser to fetch the geometries, process them to create features and add the metadata

Comment: I tried `ol.format.GML()`, `ol.format.GML2()`, `ol.format.GML3()`, `ol.format.GML32()` and `ol.format.WFS({version: '2.0.0'})` with OL 7.3.0. Nothing worked. I tried also [gml2geojson](https://github.com/deyihu/gml2geojson). Same result,  0 features in collection.

Comment: ok does that mean that openlayers can't handle the gml 3.2.2 format?

Comment: So it seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

I made my own parser to transform gml3 into GeoJSON.
I was inspired by gml2geojson.

```
//--gml parse to geojson//parse gml to Geojson
//parse GML

const parser = new DOMParser();
const GEONODENAMES = ['geometryproperty', 'shape', 'the_geom'];
function parseGML3(str,axis) {
  var srsName = '';
  var geojson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    name: "",
    crs: {  },// "'" + srsName + "'" } },
    features: []
  };
  const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  const featureCollectionEle = xmlDoc.children[0];
  const attributeGml = featureCollectionEle.getAttribute('xmlns:gml').split('/')
  const gmlVersion = attributeGml[attributeGml.length-1]
  if (!featureCollectionEle || !featureCollectionEle.nodeName || getNodeName(featureCollectionEle).indexOf('featurecollection') === -1) {
    return geojson;
  }
  let i = 0;
  const features = [];while (featureCollectionEle.children.item(i)) {
    const featureEle = featureCollectionEle.children.item(i);const nodeName = getNodeName(featureEle);
    if (nodeName.indexOf('boundedby') > -1 && featureEle.children[0].hasAttributes()) {
      srsName = featureEle.children[0].getAttribute('srsName');    
      geojson['crs'] = { type: "name", properties: { name: srsName } }
    }
    if (nodeName.indexOf('featuremember') > -1 && featureEle.children[0]) {
      features.push(featureEle.children[0]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  for (let i = 0, len = features.length; i < len; i++) {
    const f = features[i];
    const properties = getFeatureEleProperties(f);
    const geometry = getFeatureEleGeometry(f,axis);
    var type2 = geometry.type
    if (!geometry || !properties) {
      continue;
    }
    const feature = {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry,
      properties
    };
    geojson.features.push(feature);
  }
  return {type2, geojson};
}

function getFeatureEleGeometry(featureEle,axis) { 
  const children = featureEle.children || [];
  let type;
  let coordinates = [];
  let parseFeature = false;
  for (let i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (parseFeature) {
      break;
    }
    const node = children[i];
    const nodeName = getNodeName(node);
    if (!isGeoAttribute(nodeName)) { //not ['geometryproperty', 'shape', 'the_geom'];>on saute
      continue;
    }
    if (node.children[0]) {
      type = node.children[0].nodeName.split('gml:')[1] || '';
      if (!type) {
        return;
      }
    }
    if (node.children[0] && node.children[0].children[0]) {
      const nodeName = getNodeName(node.children[0].children[0]);
      let geoNodes = node.children;
      if (isMulti(nodeName)) { 
        geoNodes = flatMultiGeoNodes(geoNodes);
      }
      if (!geoNodes.length) {
        return;
      }
      for (let j = 0, len1 = geoNodes.length; j < len1; j++) {
        const geoNode = geoNodes[j];
        let coords = parseGeoCoordinates(geoNode.children,type,axis);
        if (!geoIsPolygon(type) && type.indexOf('MultiSurface')===-1) { //si pas polygone ou multipolygone
          coords = coords[0];
        }
        coordinates.push(coords);
        parseFeature = true;
      }
      if (coordinates.length === 1 && type.indexOf('Multi') === -1) {
        coordinates = coordinates[0];
      }
      
      //adaptation gml > geojson
      if ( type === 'MultiSurface'){
        type = 'MultiPolygon'
        } else if (type ==='MultiCurve'){
        type = 'MultiLineString'
      }
    }
  }
  if (!type || !coordinates.length) {
    return;
  }
  return {
    type,
    coordinates
  };
}

function getFeatureEleProperties(featureEle) {
  const children = featureEle.children || [];
  const properties = {};
  for (let i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
    const node = children[i];
    const nodeName = getNodeName(node);
    const key = getNodeName(node, false).split(':')[1];
    if (!key) {
      continue;
    }
    const value = node.textContent || '';
    properties[key] = value;
  }
  return properties;
}

function flatMultiGeoNodes(nodes) {
  const geoNodes = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    const children = nodes[i].children;
    for (let j = 0, len1 = children.length; j < len1; j++) {
      geoNodes.push(children[j].children[0]);
    }
  }
  return geoNodes;
}

function isMulti(nodeName) {
  return nodeName.indexOf('member') > -1;
}

function isGeoAttribute(nodeName) {
  for (let i = 0, len = GEONODENAMES.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (nodeName.indexOf(GEONODENAMES[i]) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function parseGeoCoordinates(coordNodes,type,axis) {
  const coordiantes = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = coordNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    const coordNode = findCoordsNode(coordNodes[i]);
    coordiantes.push(parseCoordinates(coordNode.textContent,type,axis));
  }
  return coordiantes;
}

function parseCoordinates(text,type,axis) {
  if (!text) {
    return;
  }
  const split = ' ';
  const coords = text.split(split);
  let [c1, c2] = coords;
  const coordinates = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = coords.length; i<len-1; i=i+2) {
    c1 = trim(coords[i]);
    c2 = trim(coords[i+1]);
    if ((axis.substring(0,1) ==='e' || axis.substring(0,1) ==='w') && (axis.substring(1,2) ==='n' || axis.substring(1,2) ==='s'))  {
      if (type ==='Point' || type ==='MultiPoint'){
        coordinates.push(c1, c2);
        } else {
        coordinates.push([c1, c2]);
      }
      } else if ((axis.substring(0,1) ==='n' || axis.substring(0,1) ==='s') && (axis.substring(1,2) ==='e' || axis.substring(1,2) ==='w')) {
      if (type ==='Point' || type ==='MultiPoint'){
        coordinates.push(c2, c1);
        } else {
        coordinates.push([c2, c1]);
      }
    }
  }
  return coordinates;
}

function trim(str) {
  const BLANK = ' ';
  while (str.indexOf(BLANK) > -1) {
    str = str.replace(BLANK, '');
  }
  return parseFloat(str);
}

function findCoordsNode(node) {
  let nodeName = getNodeName(node);
  while (nodeName.indexOf(':coordinates') === -1 && nodeName.indexOf(':pos') === -1) {
    node = node.children[0];
    nodeName = getNodeName(node);
  }
  return node;
}

function getNodeName(node, lowerCase = true) {
  if (lowerCase) {
    return (node.nodeName || '').toLocaleLowerCase();
    } else {
    return (node.nodeName || '');
  }
}

function geoIsPolygon(type) {
  return type.indexOf('Polygon') > -1 || type.indexOf('MultiPolygon') > -1;
}
//------------------------
//les styles
function AnnotImportStyle (type) {
  if ( type === 'Point' || type === 'MultiPoint') {
    var AnnotImportStylePoint = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#fff'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#ff0000'
        })
      })
    });
    return AnnotImportStylePoint
    } else {
    var AnnotImportStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [255, 255, 255, 0.4],
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ff0000',
        width: 2
      })
    });
    return AnnotImportStyle
  }
}
//------------------------
// drop

map.getViewport().addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
  
  const files = event.dataTransfer.files;
  const type = files.item(0).type ? files[0].type : ''
  const file_name = files.item(0).name
  
  //cas gml
  if ( file_name.indexOf ('.gml')>-1){
    async function gml (){ return files.item(0).text()}console.log('files.item(0)',files.item(0))
    gml().then((value) => {
      var gml = value;
      if ( gml.indexOf('EPSG::')>-1 ) {
        var epsg2 = gml.substring(gml.indexOf("EPSG::")+6).split('"')[0] 
        } else { return }
      var axis = ol.proj.get('EPSG:'  + epsg2)?.getAxisOrientation().substring(0,2)||'';
      if ( axis ){
        
        if ( axis.match(/[ewns]/g).length===2 ){
          var parseGml = parseGML3(gml,axis)
          var geojsonGml = parseGml.geojson
          const proj = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readProjection(geojsonGml).getCode()
          console.log('geojsonGmlProj', proj)
          const features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
          geojsonGml,
          {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
          }
          );
          const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: features
          });
          var name = file_name.substr(0, file_name.lastIndexOf('.'));
          var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: name,
            source: vectorSource,
            style: AnnotImportStyle(parseGml.type2),
            visible: true,
            boutonExtent: true,
            boutonFeatureInfo: true,
            dragAndDrop: true
          });
          map.addLayer(vector);
          vector.set('name', name);
          map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
          } else {
          alert( "le code epsg de ce fichier gml n'a pas d'axe nord et est et ne peut donc être affiché.\n Changez la projection en epsg:4326 par exemple." );
        }
        
        } else {
        alert( "le code epsg de ce fichier gml n'est pas reconnu et ne peut donc être affiché.\n Changez la projection en epsg:4326 par exemple." );
      }
      
    });
  }
});
```